# howto db_select and cross join on drupal?

Tags: database

a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (`id` int(10));INSERT INTO `a` (`id`) VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);
```

I need to make a cross join tables in drupal using db_select:

```
$query = db_select('num', 'n1');    
$query -> fields('n1', array('i'));    
$query -> innerJoin('num', '10');    
$query -> fields('n10', array('i'));    
watchdog(__FUNCTION__, $query -> __toString(), $query -> getArguments());    
$result = $query -> execute();    
$records = $result -> fetchAllAssoc('i');
```

get as a result:

> Array ( [0] => stdClass token Object ( [i] => 0 [n10_i] => 9 ) [1] =>
>   stdClass token Object ( [i] => 1 [n10_i] => 9 ) [2] => stdClass token
>   Object ( [i] => 2 [n10_i] => 9 ) [3] => stdClass token Object ( [i] =>
>   3 [n10_i] => 9 ) [4] => stdClass token Object ( [i] => 4 [n10_i] => 9
>   ) [5] => stdClass token Object ( [i] => 5 [n10_i] => 9 ) [6] =>
>   stdClass token Object ( [i] => 6 [n10_i] => 9 ) [7] => stdClass token
>   Object ( [i] => 7 [n10_i] => 9 ) [8] => stdClass token Object ( [i] =>
>   8 [n10_i] => 9 ) [9] => stdClass token Object ( [i] => 9 [n10_i] => 9
>   ) )

watchdog:
    SELECT n1.i AS i, n10.i AS n10_i FROM {num} n1 INNER JOIN {num} n10

this query in phpmyadmin gives the "multiplication" of tables: 100 rows that I deserve.

why not works through db_select in drupal?

db_select need to connect this query to a different sample already on tables Drupal, db_query would not help me =/

Comment: Please post the SQL query string that your current code produces, and the query string that you _want_ to be produced

Comment: watchdog recorded query in the log true, this for me. as I wrote, if you run it, for example through phpmyadmin, the result we get a (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join).

the query that I need to get:
SELECT n1.i AS i, n10.i AS n10_i FROM {num} n1 INNER JOIN {num} n10

if you look a result that throws db_select, we will see that the first table is selected completely, and from the 2nd "attached" only the last line.

Comment: I should have been more clear - please edit the question, and add these two pieces of information: 1. The exact SQL query that you are _trying_ to get, and 2. The exact SQL query you are _currently_ getting with the code you've already provided. Linking to the Wikipedia page for cross joins is no good, we need to see your code if you want to get an answer

Comment: Could you also elaborate on what you mean by "db_query would not help me"? db_query runs an arbitrary SQL statement against the database, so as long your SQL query string is correct, db_query will definitely work. When you add your desired SQL output to the question we can tackle that part too

Answer (score 0):

innerJoin takes 3 args: table, table_alias, and condition. ex:

```
$query->innerjoin('node', 'n', 'c.entity_id=n.nid')
```

The above would produce "...INNER JOIN node n ON c.entity_id = n.nid ..." You can add the fields form node by doing:

```
$query->fields('n', array(...));
```